# Rediscovering services in connected devices?

Tags: ios, core-bluetooth

I have a hidden service/characteristic on a BLE device, that only becomes visible if you send the "right" command to another characteristic. However, if I stay connected, and just call "discoverServices:nil" or "discoverServices:service-i-care-about", it won't find it once enabled.

I changed my firmware to make the device not hide the service on disconnection (which is what I would want), but to stick around, and I know the service is getting enabled, because I can reconnect to device, and the service shows up.

I don't want to do this, because the whole point of hiding the service is you have to send the right command to enable the service (for the record, it is a firmware update service provided by a MCU vendor, so I can't change the service to be one of "mine" or put any security around the service itself)

Is this the intended bluetooth behavior?  Or is iOS perhaps caching something and I have to do something to make it not get the cached values?

Comment: Are you sending the "service changed" characteristic indication after you have changed the gatt db?

Answer (score 0):

iOS caches any discovered peripheral and the corresponding services and characteristics for performance reasons. If you need to change the GATT table of your peripheral at any given time you have two options to tell the centrals:

1. tell the central via the Services Changed characteristic
2. change the mac address of your peripheral (not recommended but some chipset makers use this workaround, e.g., NordicSemi in the BLE bootloader)

We came across this problem as well because we need to hide the firmware update service of our embedded device until we jump to the bootloader.